# Does Box support grant type "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant"?

Tags: box-api

the documentation about OAuth 2.0 on Box's website only mentions grant type "authorization code".

Could you please confirm if Box supports grant type "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant"?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support the password grant and likely will not in the future.

Box is different from many OAuth 2 providers in that a large percentage of our customers use a single sign on provider (e.g. Ping, Okta, OneLogin, etc) to log in to Box. In those cases, Box doesn't have a password stored for the user, so it wouldn't be possible to support the password grant for them.

Our OAuth 2 web flow swallows the complexity of dealing with all of those SSO providers directly, so it's ultimately easy for a developer to make an application that works for all Box users.